# To perform only one task

Tags: linux, python-3

How can we prioritize raspberry-pi3b+ model so that if my "code on python" is running then the raspberry-pi should not perform any other task in background.
Since i have to calculate time taken by my code to complete operation, and each time i am runnning my python code on raspberry-pi, it is giving different time. 
So, i need to prioritize.
My operating system on raspberry-pi is linux.

Thanks

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking? are you saying that you want 100% of the CPU cores assigned to your python script? does your script support all the cores? are you running an X-server? which linux? Raspbian? please [edit] your question with more details. read [ask] for more information

Comment: Not Pi specific.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, and I wonder if you are the same. But you might start by reading [this article on scheduling.](https://www.tecmint.com/set-linux-process-priority-using-nice-and-renice-commands/) It might help you formulate a better question.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix you can manage the priority of processes with the command `nice`:

```
rpi ~$ sudo nice -n -20 script.py
```

This will run your script with highest priority. The nice value range is -20 to +19 where -20 is highest, 0 default and +19 is lowest. For some more information look at `man nice`.